# How to CORS Sammy.js?

Tags: jquery, cors, sammy.js

I was wondering if anyone with experience using Sammy.js has a solution to using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing?

***EDIT***

The original question was basically just asking what approach people might have used to accomplish CORS using Sammy.js, like overiding the .load() method or something like that.

The problem I'm having is that when using the .load() method while trying interact with a Sinatra api located on different domain (CORS enabled sinatra app) things aren't working as expected.

If I use an Ajax call like:

```
this.get('#/', function(context) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:4567/posts', //located on other domain
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(items) {
        $.each(items, function(i, item) {
          context.log(item.title);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

... firebug shows the items/posts in the console, but if I use .load, like:

```
this.load('http://localhost:4567/posts')

.then(function(items) {
   $.each(items, function(i, item) {
        context.log(item.title);
   });
});
```

... all is not well and the firebug console shows http://pastie.org/4051256 although firebug also indicates the json array of posts was successfully retrieved.

The behaviour also occurs if instead of logging I try to render the items in templates:

```
this.load('http://localhost:4567/posts')
.then(function(items) {
   $.each(items, function(i, item) {
     context.render('tmpl/item.mustache', {item: item})
     .appendTo(context.$element());
   });
 });
```

... bearing in mind the return is a json array of only three posts, the template is getting loaded successfully but without any data injected and also its being rendered the same amount of times as the number of 'undefined' lines in the above pastie :(

***EDIT 2***

How does the *.load* method in sammy.js treat this call differently to a jquery ajax call?

or

Why are the above issues happening?

Comment: Can you improve the question so that it is more specific? What type of help are you looking for?

Comment: This is some excellent background, and a significant improvement.  Could you give us a specific question at the end, rather than a series of statements with some question marks after them?  Are you asking for explanation of the behavior, a way to do something specific given the situation... what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an expected response type to your request. Otherwise the response will be imported as a string while looking like an array/object in Firebug. Your standard jQuery approach works because you already do that:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Using the .load() method, the expected response type can be specified like this:

```
this.load('http://localhost:4567/posts', {dataType: 'json'})
```

Or like this:

```
this.load('http://localhost:4567/posts', {json: true})
```

If the URL of your resource has "json" in its name, sammy.js will automatically set the expected response type to JSON. This is also why the example on sammy.js's website works.